# Use a modified variable in bash script, trying to change git branch programatically

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

I'm playing around with my custom commands, and I'm currently trying to change a remote Git branch programatically using bash.

```
issue() {
    if [ `git branch --list issue_$1` ]
    then
        git checkout issue_$1
    else
        git checkout -b issue_$1
        git branch -u origin issue_${1}
    fi
}
```

The idea is this function will try to find the branch issue_X, if it does it switches, otherwise it creates and sets the remote origin.

The problem is `git branch -u origin issue_${1}` I don't know how to do this, and I'm having trouble googling for it because I don't know what this process is called.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You are trying to say that you want the `else` branch to create a new branch, and mark it as tracking an upstream branch of the same name, and you don't know how to do the latter? Just push it.

Comment: @MauroCasas: I also find the title of your posting confusing. You are talking about a "modified variable", but there is no mentioning of any variable in your posting.

Comment: @MauroCasas: What problem do you have exactly when setting up the upstream branch? I'm not a *git* specialist, but the argument to `-u` should be the upstream branch name. My feeling is that a command `git branch -u origin/issue_$1 issue_$1` would be more appropriate. I suggest you remove all tags except *git* from your posting, as this question doesn't seem to be related to shell scripting, but to the naming of upstream branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to do `git branch -u origin issue_${1}`

If a remote-tracking branch `origin/issue_${1}` exists you can do `git branch -u origin/issue_${1}`.

The problem is that in your situation the remote-tracking branch doesn't exit and you have to create it:

```
git push -u origin issue_${1}
```